# Add Sharepoint's auto-generated web part for List Instances to a page programmatically

Tags: web-part

When I create a List Instance in Sharepoint, it allows me to add a view of that List as a Web Part, via the UI.

Example:

[image]

How can I add this web part programmatically via the SPWebPartManager ? (I cannot find this webpart in the Site collection web part gallery)

If this is not possible then what alternatives do I have that deliver the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of places on the web that explain how to do this.  This one was at the top of my google search, see if it helps you out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588019/programmatically-insert-a-list-as-a-webpart-in-a-webpart-page-in-wss-3-0